# Is it acceptable to wear kit from old team?

Tags: clothes

When I was in college I was on the club cycling team and it was fun, I went to a good share of races, was pretty involved with the team, etc.  Now I'm out of college and it's a few years later...is it acceptable for me to wear my old university team kits when I'm out riding casually on my own or with a few friends (*not* at events)?

Comment: I think it'd be fine because you have that historical connection.  Personally I prefer plain clothes without wording or gauche patterns, and I've gone to the point of unpicking stitching to remove names.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I guess it's a matter of opinion, and cyclists have a lot of [rules](http://www.velominati.com/the-rules/), but personally I would go for it. You were actually on the team after all. I think that the rule #17 from the above link applies here. Personally, I'd rather wear old kit from a team I was personally on than wear kit from a pro team that I have no affiliation with, or even non-pro-kit with logos plastered all over it.

Might even be a great way to start up a conversation with people who recognize the kit, either riders who are currently on the team or even just people who went to that school.

Comment: Cool, that makes sense.  I guess I just felt unsure about it since I'm not on the team anymore!

Comment: I think the only case where you shouldn't wear your old team kit is if there was a case of dishonorable discharge, like being kicked off the team for some reason.  That's the only time I could see it being in bad taste. From the way you worded the question I'm quite certain this is not the case.

Comment: Absolutely go for it! It's no different from wearing an old 'varsity top. Think of it as advertising for your old club.